# PayPal Checkout Installment Plans

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm using paypal to receive payments, but I would like to pass a form of installment to the user, but depending on the values, I wanted this to be variable, I didn't find anything in the documentation about it, is it possible?

```
  this.paypalConfig = {
  currency: 'BRL',
  createOrder: function (data, actions) {
    return actions.order.create({
      intent: "CAPTURE",
      purchase_units: [{
        "amount":
        {
          "value": self.amount,
          "currency_code": "BRL",
          "description": self.name,

        },
      }]
    });
  },
  onApprove: function (data, actions) {
    return actions.order.capture().then(function (details) {
   
  },
  onCancel: function (data) {
    // Show a cancel page, or return to cart
    console.log(data);
  },
  onError: function (err) {
    // Show an error page here, when an error occurs
    console.log(err);
  },
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For BR payments in BRL, installments can be [configured at the live PayPal Business account level](https://www.paypal.com/br/businessmanage/preferences/installmentplan)

(and if you are testing in sandbox with [a BR sandbox business account](https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Faccounts) you can also [log into Sandbox here](https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/br/businessmanage/preferences/installmentplan) to enable installments)

[More information on PayPal.com (Portuguese)](https://www.paypal.com/br/webapps/mpp/installments)

Comment: This does not solve my problem, as I would like to inform the number of installments on each occasion, not a standard.